# Neutralize bile in stomach

Tags: digestion, stomach, gerd-acid-reflux, bile

In acid reflux disease, patients are advised to eat foods that can neutralize acid in their stomach to keep the acid level in stomach low enough, for example just a small cake can efficiently reduce the acid level in stomach. Is there any same things to neutralize bile for bile reflux disease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can neutralize bile by **bile acid sequestrants,** such as cholestyramine or colestipol. However, these and other medications, such as H2 blockers and metoclopramide, *may not be very effective* ([Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/mcd/bile-reflux), [UpToDate](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/approach-to-refractory-gastroesophageal-reflux-disease-in-adults), [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6372664)).

The following *may prevent* bile reflux symptoms:

- **Lifestyle modifications:** avoiding large meals, lying down after meals, eating before sleep and smoking; maintaining health weight
- **Baclofen,** which prevents excessive relaxation of the lower esophageal sphincter and thus entering bile from the stomach into the esophagus ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3745208/))
- **Ursodeoxycholic acid,** which promotes the bile flow ([Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/mcd/bile-reflux))

Comment: thank you, but why need avoiding large meals?

Comment: Large meals, especially fatty ones, trigger the release of larger amount of bile from the gallbladder into the small intestine, which may worsen the reflux of bile into the stomach. Also, large meals can keep the lower esophageal sphincter more open than small meals, resulting in the reflux from the stomach into the esophagus.